# Java SSL Client No Self Signed Certificate

Tags: java, ssl, https, ejb

I need to send request through HTTPS. I have read a lot about SSL and there is lots about SSL on Google but no starting place where to start.

I need to connect to a web service through HTTPS and send and receive data. I am using HttpsUrlConnection to send the requests of. The web service provider does not have a self signed certificate as this would be displayed on the Internet Explorer page. The certificate is issed by COMODA High-Assurance Secure Server CA but is not self signed.

How can I connect, send and receieve data with SSL connections? Please see below code:

```
public class Sender {

      public void send(String endpoint) {
           URL url = new URL(endpoint);
           HttpsURLConnection httpsUrlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
           httpsUrlConnection.setRequestMethod(new String("POST"));
           httpsUrlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
           httpsUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");
           SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
           sc.init(null, getTrustManager(), new SecureRandom());
           httpsUrlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
           httpsUrlConnection.connect();
           OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(httpsUrlConnection.getOutputStream());
           outputStreamWriter.write(""); // writes XML data
           outputStreamWriter.flush();
           outputStreamWriter.close();
           InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(httpsUrlConnection.getInputStream());
           char i = (char) inputStreamReader.read();
           System.out.println(i);
      }

      public TrustManager[] getTrustManager() {
   TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
       public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] xcs, String string) throws CertificateException {

       }

       public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] xcs, String string) throws CertificateException {
           System.out.println("AuthType : " + " " + string);
           for(int i = 0; i < xcs.length; i++) {
               System.out.println("\t" + xcs[i].getIssuerX500Principal().getName());
               System.out.println("\t" + xcs[i].getIssuerDN().getName());
           }
       }

       public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
           return null;
       }
   }};
   return trustAllCerts;
```

}
   }

I have read about SSL on: http://wpengine.com/support/how-does-all-this-work-https-ssl-certificates-ca-public-and-private-keys-csrs/ and http://www.instantssl.com/ssl-certificate-products/https.html.

As I mentioned I don't have a self signed certificate but I have used InstallCert.java.

From the above, I receive the following Exception when the httpsUrlConnection.getInputStream() is called

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: // the URL endpoint
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: https://webaddress.co.uk/Service/services/Service?wsdl // not actual address. I can't give this but this is a sample address
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1459)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:234)
at com.screening.listener.ConnectionListenerBean.send(ConnectionListenerBean.java:191)
at com.screening.listener.ConnectionListenerBean.processMessage(ConnectionListenerBean.java:129)
at com.screening.listener.ConnectionListenerBean.listen(ConnectionListenerBean.java:107)
at com.screening.listener.ConnectionListenerBean.init(ConnectionListenerBean.java:73)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.BeanCallbackInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:1006)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackChainImpl.invokeNext(CallbackChainImpl.java:61)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInvocationContext.proceed(CallbackInvocationContext.java:109)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCallback(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:133)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.init(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:115)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:961)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackChainImpl.invokeNext(CallbackChainImpl.java:61)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:390)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:373)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.createSingletonEJB(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:518)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.access$100(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:74)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer$SingletonContextFactory.create(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:693)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.instantiateSingletonInstance(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:444)
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.initializeSingleton(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:213)
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.initializeSingleton(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:174)
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.doStartup(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:152)
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.start(EjbApplication.java:150)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:126)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:241)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:236)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:339)
at org.glassfish.kernel.embedded.EmbeddedDeployerImpl.deploy(EmbeddedDeployerImpl.java:214)
at org.glassfish.kernel.embedded.EmbeddedDeployerImpl.deploy(EmbeddedDeployerImpl.java:144)
at org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.EJBContainerImpl.deploy(EJBContainerImpl.java:128)
at org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.EJBContainerProviderImpl.createEJBContainer(EJBContainerProviderImpl.java:120)
at javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(EJBContainer.java:102)
at com.screening.Container.createEJBContainer(Container.java:22)
at com.screening.listener.ConnectionListenerBeanTest.setUpClass(ConnectionListenerBeanTest.java:24)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:292)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
```

What I am doing wrong? Is there anything to add?

From the getTrustManager() four certificates are printed in the Console.

Comment: can you show the rest of the exception log because 500 does not tell much?

Comment: Please see edit above.

Comment: I have 2 questions :Does it work if you connect with HTTP and does HTTPS work if you request from the browser?

Comment: I don't think it will work with HTTP as the web service provider is an external company. The HTTPS does work from the browser. What is seen is the XML WSDL.

Answer (score 1):

If you got an HTTP error code of any description, it is proof that the SSL part is working perfectly.

The problem here is the 500, which indicates a server error servicing your request, which has nothing to so with SSL whatsoever. You're going to have to look a the server logs to find out what caused it.

Comment: You have to see the server logs. The whole point of 500 is that it doesn't leak information about what went wrong.

Comment: I have no idea. It's your environment, not mine. Ask the people who run the server.